# Convert numeric vector to factor

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a set  of variables as factored variable :
example in variable quality the values are : `3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
I want a new FACTORED variable qual_level which has values low , medium and high such that

```
low <- quality(3,4)
medium<- quality(5,6,7)
high<- quality(8,9)
```

Hence I tried implementing following code .

```
q_levels <-  a <- factor (white_wine$quality ,
                      c(3,4,5.6,7,8,9,10), 
                      levels=1:3, 
                      labels=c("Low",  "Medium", "High"))
```

Above code throws an error :

```
Error in factor(white_wine$quality, c(3, 4, 5.6, 7, 8, 9, 10), levels = 1:3, : invalid 'labels'; length 3 should be 1 or 2
```

How can I improve the code ?

Comment: Wouldn't ```ifelse``` help you?

Answer (score 7):

Use `cut` to discretise a continuous variable:

```
x <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
cut(x, c(-Inf, 4, 7, 9), labels = c("Low",  "Medium", "High"))
#[1] Low    Low    Medium Medium Medium High   High  
#Levels: Low Medium High
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more levels, `cut()` is the way to go. But, if you have seven levels only, you can also use `fct_collapse()` in the `forcats` package.

```
library(forcats)

quality <- factor(3:9)

fct_collapse(quality,
             low = c("3", "4"),
             medium = c("5", "6", "7"),
             high = c("8", "9"))

#[1] low    low    medium medium medium high   high  
#Levels: low medium high
```

Comment: @Sotos Not that weird. Factors, by their very nature, are *discrete values*, not (continuous) numbers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I guess as a mathematician I m used to interpret discrete values/Factors as pure numbers.

Comment: @Sotos The difference is that mathematics is *untyped*. Everything is numbers (or sets, or ‹insert abstraction here›). Programming languages are typed (even if, as in the case of R, the typing is rather weak and reluctant), and the types are actually rather important.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Exactly my point (I was not familiar with the term *typed/untyped*)