# Cut numeric vector into bins

Tags: r, dataframe

I want change the values from range to names. I have three groups and I want to change these values to names like that:

```
(9.94e+03,6.3e+04] -> high
(6.3e+04,1.16e+05] -> medium
(1.16e+05,1.69e+05] -> low
```

What i need to add in this code?

```
dm2 <- mutate(dm1,
              Levels.Salary = cut(dm1$Salary,3))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert numeric vector to factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278457/convert-numeric-vector-to-factor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `labels` in `cut`:

```
cut(0:9, 3, c("low", "medium", "high"))
# [1] low    low    low    low    medium medium medium high   high   high  
#Levels: low medium high
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on GKi's answer:

```
breaks <- c(9.94e+03, 6.3e+04, 1.16e+05, 1.69e+05)
labels <- c("high", "medium", "low")

cuts <- cut(dm1, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
dm2 <- cbind(dm1, cuts)
```

But note that your labels are in decreasing order from your breaks.  Is that what you want?